# How to update or insert into same table in DB2

Tags: merge, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to update if exists or insert into if not exists in same table in DB2 (v 9.7).

I have one table "V_OPORNAC" (scheme is SQLDBA) which contains three columns with two primary keys: IDESTE (PK), IDEPOZ (PK), OPONAR

My case is, if data (OPONAR) where IDESTE = 123456 AND IDEPOZ = 0 not exits then insert new row, if exits then update (OPONAR). I have tried this:

```
MERGE INTO SQLDBA.V_OPONAROC AS O1 
USING (SELECT IDESTE, IDEPOZ, OPONAR FROM SQLDBA.V_OPONAROC WHERE IDESTE = 123456 AND IDEPOZ = 0) AS O2
    ON (O1.IDESTE = O2.IDESTE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
         OPONAR = 'test text'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT 
        (IDESTE, IDEPOZ, OPONAR) 
        VALUES (123456, 0, 'test new text')
```

Executing code above I am getting this error:

```
Query 1 of 1, Rows read: 0, Elapsed time (seconds) - Total: 0,013, SQL query: 0,013, Reading results: 0
Query 1 of 1, Rows read: 3, Elapsed time (seconds) - Total: 0,002, SQL query: 0,001, Reading results: 0,001
Warning:   DB2 SQL Warning: SQLCODE=100, SQLSTATE=02000, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.21.29
SQLState:  02000
ErrorCode: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, by using "SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1"

```
MERGE INTO SQLDBA.V_OPONAROC AS O1 
USING (SELECT 1 AS IDESTE, 2 AS IDEPOZ, 3 AS OPONAR FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) AS O2
    ON (O1.IDESTE = 123456 AND O1.IDEPOZ = 0)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
        O1.OPONAR = 'test text'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT 
        (O1.IDESTE, O1.IDEPOZ, O1.OPONAR) 
        VALUES (123456, 0, 'test new text')
```